# sbt: Dependent project does not compile first

Tags: scala, sbt

In my `build.sbt` (nothing fancy) ....

```scala
val common: Project =
  project
    .in(file("common"))
    .enablePlugins(...)
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++= ...)

val root =
project
      .in(file("."))
      .enablePlugins(...)
      .dependsOn(common)
      .aggregate(
        common,
        ....
      )
      .settings(...)
```

**Problem**

`common` does not compile before `root`, and so the compilation fails complaining that it cannot find those classes (in common)

**FYI**

- I have tried a multitude of things that I came across when searching some information on this problem (google, documentation, github issues etc.) No luck.
- sbt v1.4.9 (Play project sbt-play v2.7.9)
- The `build.sbt` is much bigger than what you see above (dependencies, tasks etc.). Otherwise, I don't think if there's anything special or tricky about it.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Why depends as well as aggregates? I guess that is the problem.

Comment: Oh, that was the last state of my trial and error. I have tried having either/both, it doesn't work.

Comment: Uhm, that is weird. `depends` have always worked for me, not a **Play** user tho. Did you _reloaded_ your build definition between change to change? Can you create a minimal git repo that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Am creating a sample project ... going be a while until I share it as a git repo.

Comment: not able to reproduce in a stand-alone project :crying:

Comment: One thing I think I can come to know is that `common/compile` in the sbt shell does not throw any errors but does not compile the source files, which I think is the root cause of the issue. Not sure why it does not consider the source files :thinking_face:

Answer (score 2):

To avoid initialisation problems try declaring projects as lazy vals

```
lazy val common = ...
lazy val root = ...
```

instead of strict vals

```
val common = ...
val root = ...
```

As a side note use `dependsOn` to establish ordering between subprojects, and not `aggregate`, because `aggregate` will not modify classpaths.

Comment: Tried adding `lazy val` .. still does not work :(

Comment: You probably have a cycle in project references. From your snippet it's clear that `root` refers to `common` - probably `common` also refers to `root` somewhere in the settings.

Comment: That makes sense ... am inspecting now for cycles.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with Mario Galic on using `lazy val`. In fact, I'd recommend using `lazy val` at all times in `build.sbt`.

If there is a cycle, like `common` referring back to `root`, one technique you can use is to use `LocalProject("project name")`, like `LocalProject("root")`:

```scala
lazy val common = (project in file("common"))
  .settings(
    Test / test := (LocalProject("root") / Test / test).value
  )
```

Comment: All my declarations in build.sbt are `lazy val`s ... am tracking to see if there is a cycle ... have not found anything so far.

Comment: Could you update the question description and copy-paste the exact error message that you are seeing? Without reproducible snippet on our machine, we can only guess at what is actually happening.

Comment: The compilation errors I am getting are not able to find classes from common.

But what I did was to move the common and couple of other sub-projects into separate projects/repo. That gave me a closure on this although it is not a solution but workaround.